# How to convert chinese text to english text in snowflake

Tags: python, unix, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datastage

I want to convert chinese text to english text in snowflake

I am having sets of chinese text wanted to convert in english in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python, you may want to look at [Google Translate API for Python](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/python). Another option is [the unofficial Google Translate Python package](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans)